# I want to count how many different value between two columns in dataframe for confusion matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

Here is a sample of my data:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'tweet': ['saya suka makanan ini sangat enak', 'rasa kuahnya kurang enak, terlalu asin', 'favorit saya nih, ayam gorengnya enak banget', 'nasi bakar di toko ini enak banget!'],
        'actual_class': ["Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive"], 'predicted_class': ["Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive"]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to count the values of True Positive, False Positive, True Negative, and False Negative between the `actual_class` and `predicted_class` columns in my dataframe **without** using `scikit-learn`. I tried to code it but I can't find the efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

If you **cannot** use `scikit-learn`, but **can** use `pandas`, you might like [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'actual_class': ["Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive"], 'predicted_class': ["Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(pd.crosstab(df.actual_class, df.predicted_class))
```

i.e.: you get the same solution you would with `import sklearn; print(confusion_matrix(df.actual_class, df.predicted_class))`:

```
predicted_class  Negative  Positive
actual_class                       
Negative                0         1
Positive                1         2
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the value counts function from pandas:

```
df['required column'].value_counts()
```

Comment: This isn't going to show tp/fp. tn/fn.